# How to validate checkbox values using express-validator?

Tags: node.js, express-validator

In my web front end form, I am using checkbox to select list of companies for each checkbox entry, I have given company name as 'value' attribute. In nodejs, I use express-validator to check the form. I am not clear how to validate and sanitize user input for these checkbox items.

I see all the example of express validator uses form parameter name to check a specific parameter (eg) check('userName') as middleware. But for checkboxes particular parameter will be present only when the user select that parameter. If I have 10 options and user select only 4 of them, then req.body will have only these parameters . And also I want all them pass through same validation check and sanitization. Please suggest how to do it.

I am using NodeJS version: 10.8
Express Validator: 5.3.0
My checkbox values are company_a1,company_a2,...company_a10. I tried to write custom Validator and check for each of the body parameter for alphanumeric value, but check is not raising error even if the value contain alphanumeric strings

```
async function validateReportParams(body, { req, loc, rpath }) {

 for (const par of Object.keys(req.body)) {
    try {
      check(req.body[par].isAlphanumberic());
    } catch (err) {
        return Promise.reject(err);
    }
  }
}
exports.genReport = [
  validateReq,
  param().custom(validateReportParams),
  async (req, res, next) => { ... }
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the same name for each checkbox than apply `isIn([])` to validate as per: https://express-validator.github.io/docs/check-api.html

```
check(req.body.checkbox.isIn(['company_a1','company_a2',...,'company_a10']));
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is a little unrelated to this question.
but if you want to use an optional **checkbox** in your form.
you can do something like this

```js
body('checkbox')
    .customSanitizer(input => {
        return Boolean(input)
    })
```